# RCharts + Shiny dynamically change chart data

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

this my first time working with both rcharts and shiny. I am trying to create a basic shiny app where users can pick stocks from dropdown menus and compare their performance in a rcharts chart ( I want to use rcharts for the interactivity).

I've managed to create the dropdown menus and the rcharts chart, but cannot get the data that the chart is created from to change. code is below:

ui.R

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("S&P 500 Retroactive Stock Comparision - 2009 and 2010"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("stockA"), uiOutput("stockB"),submitButton("Submit")),
    mainPanel(showOutput("StockPlot","NVD3"))
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
stock.names<-reactive({
  ## data from :  http://pages.swcp.com/stocks/#historical%20data 
  stocks_data<-read.table("S.P.500_data.txt",sep=",")
  colnames(stocks_data)<-c("Date","Ticker","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume") 
  stocks_data$Date<- as.Date(as.character(stocks_data$Date), "%Y%m%d")

  stocks_data$Percent.Change<-((stocks_data$High-stocks_data$Low)/stocks_data$Open)*100

  #get company names + match with ticker symbols
  library(RCurl)
  company_names1 <- "http://data.okfn.org/data/core/s-and-p-500-companies/r/constituents.csv"
  company_names2<-getURL(company_names1)
  company_names3<-read.csv(textConnection(company_names2))

  stocks_data$Company.Names<-company_names3[match(stocks_data$Ticker,company_names3$Symbol),"Name"]

  x<-sort(unique(as.character(stocks_data$Company.Names)))
  return(x)
})

library(rCharts)


shinyServer(function(input,output){
  ########
  output$stockA <- renderUI({ 
    selectInput("stockA", "Select your first stock to compare:",choices=stock.names() )
  })
  ##########
  output$stockB <- renderUI({ 
    selectInput("stockB", "Select your second stock to compare:",choices=stock.names() )
  })

  ########
stockA.name<- reactive({
  input$StockA
}) 
  #########
stockB.name<- reactive({
  input$StockB
})

#######

chart.data<-reactive({
  data<-subset(stocks_data, Company.Names %in% input$stockA | Company.Names %in% input$stockB)
 return(data)
})
  ####### 
  output$StockPlot<-renderChart2({
    plot1<-nPlot(Close~Date,data=chart.data() ,group='Company.Names',type='lineChart')
    return(plot1)
  })
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding session to your server args, and then you should be able to use

```
observeEvent(input $Submit, {

  stockA.name <- input$StockA
  stockB.name <- input$StockB

  chart.data <- subset(stocks_data, Company.Names %in% input$stockA | 
                                    Company.Names %in% input$stockB)

  output$StockPlot<-renderChart2({
    plot1 <- nPlot(Close~Date,data=chart.data(), 
                   group='Company.Names',type='lineChart')
    return(plot1)
  })

})
```

Freehanding this from my phone but I'll circle back later if it doesn't work

Comment: Sadly didn't work (unless the code below is wrong. I didn't keep the stockA/B.name code since it's not actually used):  `observeEvent(input$Submit, {
chart.data<-subset(stocks_data, Company.Names %in% input$stockA | Company.Names %in% input$stockB)

  ####### 
  output$StockPlot<-renderChart2({
    plot1<-nPlot(Close~Date,data=chart.data() ,group='Company.Names',type='lineChart')
    return(plot1)
  })
})`

Comment: i didn't see that you had a reactive outside of the server script...lot going on ..have you ever looked through this example? http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/

Comment: I did, but since it's using the quantmod package/getSymbols command it's not really useful to me. I get the general idea of reactives, just not sure how to make a reactive data frame/have the chart be created from it.

Comment: But the gist is you want to have the historical data available to the application...allow the user to filer based on a few inputs..and then view a rendering of the filtered data in a chart output, correct? All the available choices would come from the stock symbols provided in the static data file..the data set isn't streaming in from what I can tell, correct?

Comment: I retried the code with an actionButton instead of an inputButton in the ui.R code and it worked, so maybe the issue was me not having a separate name for the internal and external (user viewed text) values. (i.e. ui.R code = `actionButton("submitButton","Submit")` instead of inputButtion (thanks for the help!)